# How can I get the syntax correct when using executeQueryWithParameters to join an x++/sql statement in Microsoft Dynamics?

Tags: sql, odbc, syntax-error, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I'm currently looking at the example for "[Executing a direct SQL statement](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/dynamics-365-for/9781786468864/54f6f4f8-a202-42d0-931b-9da997a8dff4.xhtml)" in Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations Development Cookbook - Fourth Edition.

In the text, the following is used to populate`str sqlStatement`:

```
 sqlStatement = 'SELECT %1, %2 FROM %3 ' + 
          'JOIN %4 ON %3.%5 = %4.%6 ' + 
          'WHERE %7 = %9 AND %8 = %10'; 
 
          sqlStatement = strFmt( 
           sqlStatement, 
           fldAccountNum.name(DbBackend::Sql), 
           fldName.name(DbBackend::Sql), 
           tblVendTable.name(DbBackend::Sql), 
           tblDirPartyTable.name(DbBackend::Sql), 
           fldParty.name(DbBackend::Sql), 
           fldRecId.name(DbBackend::Sql), 
           fldDataAreaId.name(DbBackend::Sql), 
           fldBlocked.name(DbBackend::Sql), 
           sqlSystem.sqlLiteral(curext(), true), 
           sqlSystem.sqlLiteral(CustVendorBlocked::No, true));
```

which gets executed with

```
resultSet      = statement.executeQuery(sqlStatement);
```

However, Visual Studio warns me this is obsolete, and so I'd like to replace it using `statement.executeQueryWithParameters(sqlStatement, valueByKeyMap);`

... of course, to do this, I need to create the map, which seems to be less straightforward than I anticipated.

Currently I've assigned this:

```
str sqlStatement = @'SELECT @accountNumberField, @nameField' +
                ' FROM @vendTable v' +
                ' JOIN @partyTable p' +
                '      ON (@vendTable.@partyField = @partyTable.@recId)' +
                ' WHERE (@dataAreaIdField = @dataArea)' +
                '      AND (@blockedField = @notBlocked)';
```

and then populated the Map like:

```
        Map valueByKeyMap = SqlParams::create();

        DictField accountNumberField = new DictField(tableNum(VendTable), fieldNum(VendTable, AccountNum));
        valueByKeyMap.add('accountNumberField', accountNumberField.name(DbBackend::Sql));

        DictField nameField = new DictField(tableNum(DirPartyTable), fieldNum(DirPartyTable, Name));
        valueByKeyMap.add('nameField', nameField.name(DbBackend::Sql));

        DictTable vendTableDictionary = new DictTable(tableNum(VendTable));
        valueByKeyMap.add('vendTable', vendTableDictionary.name(DbBackend::Sql));

        DictTable partyTableDictionary = new DictTable(tableNum(DirPartyTable));
        valueByKeyMap.add('partyTable', partyTableDictionary.name(DbBackend::Sql));

        DictField partyField = new DictField(tableNum(VendTable), fieldNum(VendTable, Party));
        valueByKeyMap.add('partyField', partyField.name(DbBackend::Sql));

        DictField recId = new DictField(tableNum(DirPartyTable), fieldNum(DirPartyTable, RecId));
        valueByKeyMap.add('recId', recId.name(DbBackend::Sql));

        DictField dataAreaIdField = new DictField(tableNum(VendTable), fieldNum(VendTable, DataAreaId));
        valueByKeyMap.add('dataAreaIdField', dataAreaIdField.name(DbBackend::Sql));

        DictField blockedField = new DictField(tableNum(VendTable), fieldNum(VendTable, Blocked));
        valueByKeyMap.add('blockedField', blockedField.name(DbBackend::Sql));
        
        valueByKeyMap.add('dataArea', curext());
        valueByKeyMap.add('notBlocked', _sqlSystem.sqlLiteral(CustVendorBlocked::No, true));
```

However, when the code executes, the I get `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@partyField'.`

What is the expected syntax and how should I fix this?

Comment: DB object (table, column) name can not be parameterized via ODBC. I'm afraid you need both string formatter and parameters.

Comment: @Serg, cheers for the response.  I'm rather new at this.  Could you please elaborate what that should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with  MS dynamics programming. Using c#
string interpolation, kind of

```
String accountNumberField = ...;
String nameField = ... ;
//... other variables for the string interpolation below
String statement =$"SELECT {accountNumberField}, {nameField} 
                  FROM {vendTable} v 
                 JOIN {partyTable} p 
                       ON (v.{partyField} = p.{recId}) 
                  WHERE ({dataAreaIdField} = @dataArea) 
                       AND ({blockedField} = @notBlocked)";

  // Create and set values only Sql parameters `@dataArea` and `@notBlocked` with your tool here. Assotiate them with sqlStatement  which text is statement
  // ...
  
 resultSet  = statement.executeQuery(sqlStatement);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but this is what I am trying to replace as the `executeQuery` method has been marked obsolete.  To replace it, we should use a new method which takes the parameters separately.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/query-with-parameters

Comment: The paper says new MS Dynamics API relies on MS SQL Server  statement parameters. Those parameters can be only data values and never object names.  Constructing all the rest query text is solely  a developer responsibility.

Comment: In other words, if I understand you correctly, interpolation needs to happen twice?  Once for the object names, directly into the statement, and then later a second time to fill the values for the WHERE clause? .... I can try it.

Comment: The query parameters processing includes a lot more then plain interpolation so the query is protected against sql injection with bad data values.

Comment: I kind of feel this undermines the point of passing the parameters in separately when I've already used string formatting to insert 80% of my values...   the X++ equivalent is what it seems to require.